# Magento 2: Change font from helvertica

Tags: magento2

Can any one help me to change the fonts in Magento 2 from helvertica ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check this link : [font](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/using-fonts.html)

thanks !!